# Exporting set of lat/long coordinates to SVG using tool or code?

Tags: coordinates, svg

Suppose I have a set of coordinates in latitude and longitude.

What would be the easiest way to export those to an SVG file?

I'd rather do this programatically (any language or library will do) rather than manually, but can revert to that if necessary.

Comment: All points connected produce one shape or several shapes ? and if several shapes you connect the points based on what ?

Comment: Acutally I have a list of list. 1st list of points represents a shape - 2nd list represents a second shape - ... All those shapes are next to each other

Comment: You want to do it using programming or using a tool ?

Comment: The best would be using a tool

Comment: @Shady - you can answer the other question instead

Comment: @iant I was in process of answering but you marked it as DUPLICATE so I cannot answer.

Comment: but you CAN answer the other question - use copy and paste if necessary

Comment: The other question asked for a programatically answer not a tool. Anyway thx to @Shady I will check QGIS

Comment: I know @Weedoze, that's why I didn't answer there (some users may down vote if I answer there as question about programmatic not manual)

Comment: @Shady Downvoting answers is relatively rare and no one has downvoted the Manual Method answer here.  The original question left the door open for manual (tool) answers.  If asked today I think we would have sought to tighten the question's scope.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo I posted my answer, you are right. Me myself I got use of several answers for a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have your spatial data in a PostGIS database, try [`ST_AsSVG`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_AsSVG.html), e.g.:

```
postgis=# SELECT ST_AsSVG(ST_MakePoint(1797227.3141, 5431330.2559));
                     st_assvg
--------------------------------------------------
 cx="1797227.3141000001" cy="-5431330.2559000002"
(1 row)
```

(The linestring and polygon conversions are much more tricky, and thus very useful to have.)

If you don't use a database and are familiar with C, you can use the [liblwgeom library](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/postgis-doxygen/da/de7/liblwgeom_8h.html) (from PostGIS, but independent of PostgreSQL). See the [API docs for `lwgeom_to_svg`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/postgis-doxygen/da/de7/liblwgeom_8h_0758f75f2a574f714cfbea317173d085.html#0758f75f2a574f714cfbea317173d085).

*Note*: these methods only provide parts of the SVG geometric elements, not the file.

Answer (score 2):

Manual Method -- The [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=svg) takes in coordinates and can export them to a variety of formats, including SVG.

Comment: Is there a way to look at the source code that does the lat/lng to pixel coordinate conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Another manual method in QGIS is to use **SimpleSVG** plugin.    [image]

**Reference:**
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/simplesvg/